# Regex - match a number in-between any character except other numbers/letters

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'm banging my head off the wall here trying to figure out a regex...

So I have a product id `9984`

I'm trying to create a regex (Javascript).

The following examples **should** match:

```
9984
"9984"
'9984'
 9984    //i.e. spaces are OK
```

The following examples **shouldn't** match (i.e. `9984` has either numbers or letters [a-zA-Z0-9] on either side):

```
a9984
9984x
z9984B
199841
299842
99843
499844
Q9984c
etc.
```

I'm trying the regex `/[^0-9]?9984?[^0-9]+/` at:

https://regex101.com/r/qX6vE1/1

But I just cannot get it to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\b9984\b
```

Try this.This should work.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/fG5pZ8/17

```
There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:

    Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
    After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
    Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.
```

Comment: this also allows tabs (probably okay just not mentioned by OP)